# Why is the string group not a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

The string group $String(n)$ is by definition a 3-connected cover of $Spin(n)$. This definition determines the homotopy type of the string group.

[*In a previous version of this question I screwed up the definition and caused some confusion, see the comments below.*]

A common argument is saying that "the string group cannot be a Lie group because it has vanishing $\pi_3$". This is obviously not a complete argument because $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a nice Lie group with vanishing $\pi_3$.

What is the correct statement about Lie group structures on the string group, and how does one prove it?

Comment: Konrad -- unless $n\leq2$ there is no group at all satisfying the conditions of the posting.

Comment: @algori could you give a reference for this (or a sketch of an argument)?

Comment: Michele -- a covering group of a Lie group *is* a Lie group. So either  the connected component of the unit is a torus of $\pi_3\neq 0$. I presume the author meant something else but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: ... *or* $\pi_3\neq 0$. Argh!

Comment: The string group is given by killing pi_0, pi_1,pi_2,pi_3.  So for O(n) it ends up being the homotopy fiber of the map G ---> K(Z,3).  Certainly what you guys are saying means it can't be represented by a compact Lie group. What does it's rational cohomology look like? Well if I am thinking about this the right way it doesn't anymore satisfy Poincare duality?

Comment: I think your definition needs to be revised to make the string group uniquely defined.  In particular, String(n) should be the universal 3-connected term in the Moore-Postnikov tower of $O(n)$, and the definition given above does not exclude higher terms.  Some of the commenters may be confused because it is not a covering group in the usual sense of covering spaces.

Comment: G should be Spin there...Hopefully this argument shouldn't be totally wrong but I can't work it out in my head...The idea is to look at rational cohomology. Spin(n), being a compact Lie group should have rational cohomology isomorphic to the exterior algebra on odd spheres, $\Lambda(x_3,...x_{2i+1})$. We have a fibration $String(n) \mapsto Spin(n) \mapsto K(Z,3)$ which should give rise to a fibration $K(Z,2) \mapsto String(n) \mapsto Spin(n)$. Now apply the rational Serre spectral sequence and use the multiplicative structure on K(Z,2) this should be calculable, what happens?

Comment: In what way is your cohomology calculation related to the question, Daniel?

Comment: Actually this method could never work because rationally the map from $SU(2)=Spin(3) \mapsto K(Z,3)$ is a rational homotopy equivalence. But I think if you do it integrally you get torsion cohomology groups in infinitely many dimensions so it can't be a finite dimensional Lie group. @Mariano Well I interpreted the question as why isn't this group a finite dimensional non-compact Lie group. Of course it could be some kind of infinite dimensional Lie group but then the facts about $pi_3$ don't seem relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result is that a compact, connected simple Lie group $G$ has $\pi_3(G) = \mathbb{Z}$. Simple covering space or subgroups arguments should get you to $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ which is all that matters. For that matter start with the 1-connected $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$.

[OK, a short train ride later, now I'm home from work. To continue...]

The fibre of the 3-connected cover is a 2-type, and in the case of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ this is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, so at the very least, $\mathrm{String}(n)$ can't be finite-dimensional. If one could construct a primitive[1] $PU(\mathcal{H})$-bundle on $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ whose Dixmier-Douady classs was the generator $\langle -,[-,]\rangle \in H^3(\mathrm{Spin}(n),\mathbb{Z})$, then you would have an infinite-dimensional Lie group model for $\mathrm{String}(G)$ (here $\mathcal{H}$ is a infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space, $PU(\mathcal{H})$ is then a smooth model for $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, if we take the norm topology, making it a Banach Lie group).

([1] Primitive in the sense that for the group operations $G\times G\to G$ and $(-)^{-1}:G\to G$ there are bundle maps covering them.)

I don't know if this is possible or not, but I'm sure this idea has occurred to someone before, and since we haven't seen it, there might be a reason (well, I haven't seen it and everyone goes on about $\mathrm{String}_G$ only being a topological group).

Comment: David -- re $pi_3(G)=\mathbf{Z}$: what about tori?

Comment: I'm only thinking about the definition of String proper.

Comment: oh yes, it says "simple". Need to get some sleep.

Comment: David, can you complete your argument by explaining why a 2-type can't be finite-dimensional?

Comment: Ok, it can't be finite-dimensional because it has cohomology in infintely many degrees, see Daniel's answer below.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph - and probably this reference should be given here anyway: this very construction has been carried out by Stolz in the fifth section of [A conjecture concerning positive Ricci curvature and the Witten genus](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01446319) (Math. Ann. **304** (1996) 785–800), where he proves that there is such a model and it is a topological group, with the map to $G$ a homomorphism.

Answer (score 10):

To follow up, there is now an infinite-dimensional Lie group model of String:

- Thomas Nikolaus, Christoph Sachse, Christoph Wockel, *A Smooth Model for the String Group*, Int. Math. Res. Not. **16** (2013) 3678-3721, doi:[10.1093/imrn/rns154](https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rns154), arXiv:[1104.4288](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4288).

Answer (score 7):

As David Roberts is saying it's conceivable the string group could be represented by an infinite dimension manifold. I'm totally agnostic on that, but as I interpret the question it's asking why it's not equivalent (as an H-space?) to a non-compact finite dimensional Lie group (David Roberts also explains that for a compact simply connected Lie group we always have $\pi_3$ non vanishing). I think though the underlying space has cohomology in infinitely many dimensions. Let me illustrate this in the case of $\mathrm{String}(3)$. So we have a Serre spectral sequence for the fibration $K(\mathbb{Z},2)\to \mathrm{String}(3) \to S^3$. Now thinking of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as the cohomology ring of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, the differential has to be $d:x \mapsto e$, the generator for the cohomology of $S^3$. So using the Leibnitz rule, $x^2\mapsto 2x\otimes e$,  $x^3 \mapsto 3x^2\otimes e$... etc. This means that $H^5(\mathrm{String}(3))= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $H^7(\mathrm{String}(3))=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$... etc

Comment: Daniel, sorry for this stupid question, can you specify a reference for the cohomology of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$? If it really has cohomology in infinitely many degrees, than one can use David's argument above to show that $String(n)$ cannot be finite-dimensional for all $n$!

Comment: $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$, and its cohomology is a polynomial algebra on a generator in degree 2; most algebraic topology texts should cover this.

Comment: Well it just seemed a little subtle because the string group is only defined up to H-space equivalence so it seemed possible that you could have an infinite manifold that is homotopy equivalent to a f.d. one.